# Ruby Singleton attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, singleton

I'm trying to create a class that includes the [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module while using `attr_accessor`. This doesn't seem to be working though.

```
require 'singleton'

class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  include Singleton
end

Foo.bar = 'foobar'
```

This gives the error:

```
undefined method `bar=' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are calling a class method instead of an instance method which you don't have implemented. Singelton is a class with only one existent instance. You should be doing the call on an instance and not on the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Singleton` does not change the way `attr_accessor` works. It only ensures that you can have only one instance. So you have to call `attr_accessor` within the eigenclass, just as you do without `Singleton`.

```
class Foo
  singleton_class.class_eval{attr_accessor :bar}
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like this solution because people that use my gem won't have to do `Foo.instance.blah...`

Comment: Note `instance_eval` or `class_eval` can be used here. Alternatively, one could write `singleton_class.public_send(:attr_accessor, :bar)`.

Comment: Yet another option is to open the singleton class:

`class Foo
      include Singleton
      class << self
        attr_accessor :bar
      end
    end`

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
     Foo.instance.bar = 'foobar'
```

Documented [**Here**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html#label-Implementation) and [**Here**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html#label-Usage)

Answer (score 1):

Methods defined using `attr_accessors` are instance methods, you are trying to call the method `bar=` on the `Foo` class, that doesn't define it. You have to get the instance of `Foo` first and then call `bar=` on it:

```
Foo.instance.bar = "whatever"
```